# Is there a relationship between the value of the integral of f(x) between 0 and infinity and the value of f(-x) between 0 and infinity?

Tags: integration

I have used keyhole contour integration to calculate the value of the integral of f(x) between 0 and infinity, I have no information about whether f(x) is odd or even etc. Is there a way to calculate the value of the integral of f(-x) between 0 and infinity. Is there a relationship between the two.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you trying to compare $\int_{0}^\infty f(-x)\; dx$ and $\int_{0}^\infty f(x)\; dx$? They are unrelated in general (think about piecewise-defined functions). On the other hand, $\int_{-\infty}^0 f(-x)\; dx = \int_{0}^\infty f(x)\; dx$ for every function (as soon as the two integrals make sense).